# Java UI project look and feel FlatLaf

Tags: java, netbeans, look-and-feel

after doing some changes in the Netbeans UI, I realized that also my project changed the look and feel. I've been trying to change the look and feel of my project but without success. This is the code that I put in to force the change, but no effect to the app UI:

```
package com.mycompany.main;

import com.mycompany.panels.GUIJFrame;
import com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatDarkLaf;
import javax.swing.UIManager;


/**
 *
 * @author myself
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new FlatDarkLaf());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        GUIJFrame jframe = new GUIJFrame();
        jframe.setTitle("Campus IT Asset Manager");
        jframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Netbeans**

[image: Netbeans]

Is there any chance that Netbeans might be defining the look and feel of the app in another setting? The funny part is that I ran the **same code from Eclipse and the correct FlatDarkLaf look and feel UI got displayed**. Therefore, Netbeans may be interfering somehow...

**Eclipse**

[image: Eclipse]

Thanks,

Fabio

Comment: does it throw any exception while running in Netbeans?

Comment: No exceptions are thrown...

Answer (score 1):

I just realized a had a different class with the Main method and that one was being considered. I commented it out and the code above worked.

Fabio